# Excel VBA - How to find blank cell and sum from active cell up to blank cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to find the first blank cell and sum the data below it at the last blank cell.

```
Dim r As Range
Dim lngRowStart As Long
If Range("A1").Formula <> "" Then
    lngRowStart = 1
Else
    lngRowStart = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
End If
    Set r = Cells(lngRowStart, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
If Left(r.Offset(-1, 0).Formula, 1) <> "=" Then
        r.FormulaR1C1 = "=Subtotal(9,R[-" & r.Row - lngRowStart & "]C:R[-1]C)"
End If
```

But this assumes that the data is in column A and for the first set of continuous data, how to modify it for any active cell to sum the above continuous data?

For example:

```
2

4

3

Blank (SUM ABOVE=9)

1

3

2

Blank (SUM ABOVE=6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **UDF** below (explanation inside the code's comments):

```
Function SumContinRange(CurCell As Range) As Double    
    Dim RngStart As Range, SumRng As Range        

    If CurCell <> "" Then
        ' find the first empty cell using the Find function
        Set RngStart = Columns(CurCell.Column).Find(what:="", After:=CurCell, LookIn:=xlValues)
    Else
        ' find the first empty cell using the Find function
        Set RngStart = Columns(CurCell.Column).Find(what:="", After:=CurCell, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    End If

    ' set the Sum Range
    Set SumRng = Range(RngStart.Offset(-1, 0), RngStart.Offset(-1, 0).End(xlUp))

    SumContinRange = WorksheetFunction.Sum(SumRng) ' return this value   
End Function
```

Then, test it by passing the `ActiveCell` using the `Sub` below:

```
Sub TestFunc()

If ActiveCell.Value <> "" Then
    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Offset(1) = SumContinRange(ActiveCell)
Else
    ActiveCell = SumContinRange(ActiveCell)
End If  

End Sub
```